# In kubuntu (KDE 5), can one use 'Save session' to restore an arbitrary application, even one that runs under Wine?

Tags: kubuntu, wine, kde, session, konsole

When I manually save a session in `kubuntu` (KDE Menu -> Leave -> Save session), then, after a reboot, some applications are restored, but others are not.

Among the applications that *are* restored are `Dolphin`, `Kate`, `Kile`, `Okular`, and `Firefox`.

Among the applications that *aren't* restored are `Konsole`, `MatLab`, `Mathematica`, and `PDF-XChange Editor` (this last one runs under `Wine`).

**Question:**

Is there a way to use 'Save session' to restore an arbitrary application upon reboot?

In particular, is there a way to use 'Save session' to restore the `PDF-XChange Editor` (running under `Wine`)? How about the `Konsole`?

**Details about my system:**

Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.8
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8

Comment: Sad that nobody ever answered this. Did you manage to find an answer?

Comment: @pglpm Unfortunately, I didn't…